# Error 500 Deploy django con Apache

Tags: django, apache

estoy intentando realizar un deploy(producción) a Django con Apache mod_wsgi, dentro de ello he seguido los pasos de acuerdo a Digital Ocean [Tutorial Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-centos-7).

pero tengo este error:

> Internal Server Error(500)
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.

Para poner en producción tengo el archivo **django.conf** asi:

```
Alias /static /home/roo/Documentos/myproject/myproject/static
<Directory /home/roo/Documentos/myproject/myproject/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/roo/Documentos/myproject/myproject/myproject>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-path=/home/roo/Documentos/myproject:/home/ro$
WSGIProcessGroup myproject
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/roo/Documentos/myproject/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py
```

Mi estructura es  la siguiente:

```
/home
  >roo
    >Documentos
     >myproject
       >myproject
         >db.sqlite3
         >manage.py
         >myproject
           >settings.py
           >wsgi.py
           ...
         >static
         >templates
       >myprojectenv
        ..
        ..
```

Analizando el log de errores me genera:

```
[Wed Apr 03 10:51:48.272155 2019] [:error] [pid 1688] (13)Permission denied: [remote ::1:252] mod_wsgi (pid=1688, process='myproject', application='localhost.localdomain|'): Call to fopen() failed for '/home/roo/Documentos/myproject/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py'.
[Wed Apr 03 10:51:48.273721 2019] [mime_magic:error] [pid 1690] [client ::1:52237] AH01512: mod_mime_magic: can't read `/home/roo/Documentos/myproject/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py'
[Wed Apr 03 10:51:48.274032 2019] [mime_magic:error] [pid 1690] [client ::1:52237] AH01512: mod_mime_magic: can't read `/home/roo/Documentos/myproject/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py'
[Wed Apr 03 10:51:48.274320 2019] [:error] [pid 1688] (13)Permission denied: [remote ::1:252] mod_wsgi (pid=1688, process='myproject', application='localhost.localdomain|'): Call to fopen() failed for '/home/roo/Documentos/myproject/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py'.
```

en resumidas cuentas es por el permiso que no puede acceder, como podria darle dicho permiso, gracias de antemano.

Comment: ponlo en /var/www/html que es el directorio de apache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buscando por la red halle la solución(temporal) practica a esto:

Deshabilitar el **SELINUX**:

```
sudo nano /etc/selinux/config
```

Y cambiando la siguiente linea:

```
SELINUX=disabled
```

con esto evito le problema de los permisos y forzamos a acceder a ellos.

Si alguien le sirve dejo la fuente: [producción Django en Centos 7](http://pythonpiura.org/posts/2016/04/14/servir-aplicaciones-django-con-apache-y-mod_wsgi-en-centos-7/)

Answer (score 0):

Se podría hacer de dos maneras:

opcion 1: mover el proyecto al diretorio de apache

```
 mv /home/roo/Documentos/myproject /var/www/html
```

opcion2 dar la propiedad de tu proyecto al usuario de apache:

```
 chown -R www-data:www-data /home/roo/Documentos/myproject
```

Si usas una version basada en fedora o centos en lugar de `www-data` seria `httpd`

Aunque me inclino por la primera opción, ya que dar permisos en directorios de tu usuario puede ser ariesgado por seguridad

Comment: saludos, he probado de las dos maneras primero con la opcion 2 y luego con la opcion 1 cambiando tambien las rutas de mi "django.conf"..pero aun no logro hacer.... gracias por tu respuesta..!!

Comment: y que error te muestra?

Comment: puedes hacer un ls -l para ver las propiedades de la carpera

Comment: resultado: "total 0
drwxrwxr-x. 5 roo apache 84 abr  3 10:01 myproject
drwxrwxr-x. 5 roo apache 52 abr  3 09:46 myprojectenv
"

Comment: que sistema operativo usas?

Comment: uso Centos 7...

Comment: prueba dando permisos de lectura `chmod 775 /home/roo/Documentos/myproject/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py`

Comment: gracias pero el error persiste.. :(

Comment: y que error te muestra?

Comment: al acceder al localhost me aparece la tipica pantalla de apache, movi nuevamente mi directorio "myproject" a Documentos y el error es el mismo de mi pregunta "500"

Comment: prueba con chmod 777 jamas deberia de hacer pero solo pureba

Comment: gracias de hecho ese tambien fue un comando que realize primero pero sin resultados, voy a intentar nuevamente el tutorial y probar